# Environment variable not visible in Python application started from pm2

Tags: python, environment-variables, pm2

I'm using a server for the first time. It has Ubuntu 18.04.
I've never worked with that OS, but after some guides I managed to get my code working, except for the environment variable.
In `~/.bashrc` at the end of file I added `export KEY="123asd"`.
Then I reloaded the terminal.
I checked if my environment variable is loaded via `printenv KEY` and it shows the correct value.
In my `main.py` there's:

```
import os
import telebot

API_KEY = os.getenv("KEY")
bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_KEY)
```

When I run it with `pm2 start main.py --interpreter=python3` there's an error in logs:

```
raise Exception('Bot token is not defined')
Exception: Bot token is not defined
```

If I understand correctly it means that `API_KEY` is `None` so there's a problem with the environment variable.
I tried giving `API_KEY` an actual value, not an environment variable, and it worked fine.
So what else do I need to do to use an environment variable properly?

Comment: Perhaps Python is not execute on bash session

Comment: Environment variables (aka "env vars") are not global. They are private to each process. When a process, like your shell, starts a new (child) process it hands that process a set of env vars that may, or may not, be a simple copy of its env vars. What is the `pm2` command in your example? I'm guessing it's https://pm2.io/; specifically, https://pm2.io/blog/2018/09/19/Manage-Python-Processes. That document implies that `pm2` has to be configured to pass the desired env vars to your Python program -- it doesn't simply inherit those of the current shell.

Comment: If my guess about the `pm2` command in my previous comment is correct then your problem has nothing to do with Python or Ubuntu Linux. The problem is your understanding of how the PM2 application works.

Comment: Answers should be added with the "Add an Answer" button, not as edits to the question. That's true even if you're not sure if the answer is the best possible one: a separate answer can be upvoted, downvoted and commented on separate from the question itself.

Comment: I’ve never had much luck with environment variables in `.bashrc`. I use the dotenv package and have my vars in a `.env` in the project root directory. https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking in the wrong place.
If I want to use `pm2` then I need to create a `ecosystem.config.js` file and give it my variable. Like this:

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
          name: "main.py",
    env: {
        KEY: "123asd"
    }
  }]
}
```

It works, only I'm not sure if it's correct since there are more than 1 processes of my main.py (1 online, others are erorred)